# is it even possible to get an FPS Counter for a program in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, overlay, frame-rate

Ive tried almost every method of getting an fps counter for c# overlay. However none of them seem to be working. Literally None.

This is my code for getting the process i want the overlay to find and this is used for the overlay to follow the process window so its always ontop, im wanting an fps counter that works on the targetwindow so then i can display it in a label on my overlay.

```
        private IntPtr FindTargetWindow(string windowTitle)
        {
            IntPtr targetHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(windowTitle))
                {
                    targetHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return targetHandle;
        }

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

            targetWindowHandle = FindTargetWindow("MinutesTillDawn");

            this.Topmost = true;

            updateTimer.Start();

        }
```

I dont have any other code to provide since i have tried way too many methods and neither of them work

Comment: [GameOverlay.Net](https://github.com/michel-pi/GameOverlay.Net)

Comment: @Jimi Isnt this just an overlay libary? I have the overlay working fine its the fps counter part i cant work out.

Comment: Well, it's already written, so you can implement that existing functionality or study the code and understand how it works. For example, you have to set the high-resolution periodic multimedia timer, keeping in mind that this may or may not, depending on the System version, change the behavior of all processes, so you have to do it in a *sensible* manner. It also depends what kind of window you want to *overlay*, which also changes how the FPS are measured. This requires some low-level API calls (a couple undocumented, to address issues with some games). etc.

Comment: Games have a game loop will recalculate stuff each iteration and drive rendering. Wpf doesn't really work like that. Setting animation aside. Nearest equivalent is the dispatcher processing it's queue. You do something, a visual is invalidated. When the dispatcher gets round to it, some rendering happens.

Comment: Or is this Wpf measuring some other exe, like some game you installed?

Comment: @Andy Yeah im needing it to measure some game i installed.

Comment: The win10 game bar is no good to you?

Comment: @Andy well the game bar is good but im wanting to use my own overlay as it has over things on there that i need including temps etc.. But i wish i could somehow use the gamebar performace widget and get the fps from there as it works really well but i dont believe there is a way of doing that